# POST file(image with multipart/form-data) with form-data in android

Tags: android, web-services

I am working on an android app. Here, i need to update an image on server. Web Service can accept 3 fields here. 
1. image type (String)
2. file       (File) 
3. user_id    (String)

[image]

So how can i implement this functionality with the use if some API in android. I used Volley till now for server communication but i got stuck here. I have tried to implement this functionality by use of HttpClient but this is not working and not sufficient one.

Comment: You can use retrofit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use retrofit for multipart content. It is lightning fast.

Write the following in APInterface , add photo MultiPart body and all other params in string RequestBody

```
@Multipart
@POST("MethodName")
Call<Response> updateUser(@Part MultipartBody.Part photo,
                          @Part("string") RequestBody string);
```

these lines in ApiClient

```
     public static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("url").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(okHttpClient).build();

    return retrofit;
}
```

Send your file to server using these Multipart retrofit technique in your activity.

```
 //path is the file path 
 File image = new File("" + (String) path);

        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), image);
        MultipartBody.Part fileImage = null;
        if (requestFile.contentLength() != 0)
            fileImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", image.getName(), requestFile);
```

and send that file using retrofit call it will work.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping me. Actually, i am new for this retrofit library. I didn't get what you want to make me understand by above example. Can you refer some document or some blog where i can read about it more. I tried to search about this library but i did not find the relevant content yet.

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/    

Check out this link for all the methods regarding retrofit.

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

And refer this for an example